# Python script that is not running in Windows server 2012

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-server-2012

I have a script that has successfully run for a long time. Recently one of my servers was upgraded into Server 2012 and the script is failing to run. It's purpose is to connect to a port and receive some data. The problem here looks like some weird characters that I receive back which I don't know where are they coming from. Any help would much appreciated.

### FAILED:

> "C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\gui_update_client.py" hostname/IP address
> 10000 Filename     Server: hostname/IP address, Port: 10000, Master:
> Filename Connected to nn.nnn.nnn.nn on port 10000 GUI update request
> sent: Filename Data received: €$Y{gï Data received:  Socket error:
> No data received.

### Succesfull:

> "C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\gui_update_client.py" hostname/IP address
> 10000 Filename Server: hostname/IP address, Port: 10000, Master:
> Filename Connected to hostname/IP address on port 10000 GUI update
> request sent: Filename Data received: Keep alive
>
> Keep alive received Data received: GUI update completed
>
> Response read: GUI update completed

```
# Script Arguments
import sys
# Network Client
import socket
# Logging
import logging
# Other
import time
import os

TIMEOUT = 60
DELIM = '\n'
KEEP_ALIVE_MSG = 'Keep alive'

NO_UPDATES_FOUND = 'No GUI updates found'
UPDATE_COMPLETED = 'GUI update completed'

# Check required arguments
try:
    server = sys.argv[1]
    port   = int(sys.argv[2])
    master = sys.argv[3]
except:
    print 'Usage: {0} server port master'.format(sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

print 'Server: {0}, Port: {1}, Master: {2}'.format(server, port, master)

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.create_connection((server, port))
sock.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
print 'Connected to {0} on port {1}'.format(server, str(port))

# Send request and get response
response = ''
try:
    # Send GUI update request
    sock.sendall(master + DELIM)
    print 'GUI update request sent: {0}'.format(master)

    # Read the response
    data  = ''
    while response == '':
        # Read the response
        split = ''
        while split != DELIM:
            # Buffer the data in small chunks
            datum = sock.recv(1024)
            print 'Data received: {0}'.format(datum)
            if datum == '':
                raise socket.error('No data received.')
            data += datum
            (response, split, remainder) = data.partition(DELIM)

        # Check for keep alive response
        while response == KEEP_ALIVE_MSG:
            print 'Keep alive received'
            data = remainder
            (response, split, remainder) = data.partition(DELIM)
            if split != DELIM:
                response = ''

    # Response received
    print 'Response read: {0}'.format(response)
except socket.timeout as err:
    print 'Timeout error: {0}'.format(str(err))
except socket.error as err:
    print 'Socket error: {0}'.format(str(err))
finally:
    # Clean up the connection
    sock.close()
    logging.info('Connection to {0} on port {1} closed.'\
                 .format(server, str(port)))

    if response == UPDATE_COMPLETED or response == NO_UPDATES_FOUND:
        os.environ['ERRORLEVEL'] = "0"
        exit()
    else:
        os.environ['ERRORLEVEL'] = "1"
        exit(1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post gui_update_client.py?

Comment: @Wyrmwood I have edit per your request. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for having a look. I have found what the issue is here. The script is fine. The problem here is that windows listening port is on a different network. When the server was upgraded to 2012 it took as a default a different network card for the service running. That's why the reply comes with weird characters.